# How can I easily see that $|\operatorname{Hom}_F(\prod_{i\in\Delta}F,F)|>|\prod_{i\in\Delta}F|$ when $\Delta$ is infinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

> **Corollary 4.8:** If $|\Delta|=n<\infty$, then $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom(\prod_{i\in\Delta}V_i,W)\cong\prod_{i\in\Delta}\Hom(V_i,W)$.
>
> In general, Corollary 48 [sic] is false when $|\Delta|=\infty$.  For example, if $W=F$ and $V_i=F$ for all $i\in\Delta$, then the reader can easily see that $|\Hom_F(\prod_{i\in\Delta}F,F)|>|\prod_{i\in\Delta}F|$ when $\Delta$ is infinite.  Since $\Hom_F(F,F)\cong F$, we see that $\Hom(\prod_{i\in\Delta}F,F)$ cannot be isomorphic to $\prod_{i\in\Delta}\Hom(F,F)$.
>
> <sub>*Brown, William C.*, A second course in linear algebra, Wiley-Interscience Publication. New York etc.: Wiley. x, 264 p., £ 30.50 (1988). [ZBL0642.15001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0642.15001).</sub>

Ironically, I fail to see that $|\Hom_F(\prod_{i\in\Delta}F,F)|>|\prod_{i\in\Delta}F|$ when $\Delta$ is infinite.

I interpret $\Hom_F(\prod_{i\in\Delta}F,F)$ to mean the set of all $F$-linear transformations mapping from $\prod_{i\in\Delta}F=F\times F\times\cdots$ to $F$, but I do not understand what $|\Hom_F(\prod_{i\in\Delta}F,F)|$ and $|\prod_{i\in\Delta}F|$ actually mean.

If $|\cdot|$ allows me to obtain the dimension of the $\Hom$ and the dimension of the vector space $F\times F\times\cdots$, then shouldn't $|\prod_{i\in\Delta}F|$ be $\infty$ because $F\times F\times\cdots$ is a vector space of infinite dimension?  From this, wouldn't it hold that $|\Hom_F(\prod_{i\in\Delta}F,F)|\leqslant|\prod_{i\in\Delta}F|$?

From another viewpoint, is it not possible to define a meaningful linear transformation $\Psi:\Hom(\prod_{i\in\Delta}V_i,W)\to\prod_{i\in\Delta}\Hom(V_i,W)$ by $T\mapsto(T\theta_1,T\theta_2,\cdots)$ where $\Psi$ is both injective and surjective, for infinite $\Delta$?  Here, $\theta_q:V_q\to V$ is the $q$-th injection.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: $|\cdot|$ means cardinality. For every set $,\Delta$ it is true that $Hom(\bigoplus_{i \in \Delta}V_i,W)\cong\prod_{i \in \Delta}Hom(V_i,W)$, but, when $\Delta$ is infinite $\bigoplus_{i \in\Delta}V_i \subsetneq \prod_{i \in\Delta}V_i$ and 'intuitively' $Hom(\prod_{i \in\Delta}V_i,W)$ should be bigger than $Hom(\bigoplus_{i \in\Delta}V_i,W)$, if you can prove that $|Hom(\prod_{i \in\Delta}F,F)|>|\prod_{i \in\Delta}F|$ ($F \cong Hom(F,F)$), then those spaces cannot be isomorphic. Corollary 4.8 is true assuming that $\Delta$ is finite since finite direct products and finite direct sums coincide.

Comment: @GilbertoLópez I have not yet learnt $\oplus$.  Is there another path to feel the intuition?  I promise to read your comment again once I read through $\oplus$.

Comment: in that case, Lord Shark the Unknown gives a better idea.

Comment: @FrenzyLi : Sorry for this very late comment but since a few years have passed, I really wanted to know what was your ultimate experience with these gaps in explanation in Brown's book. I recently picked up this book and had this same question and was baffled by the complicated explanation below.

Comment: @sadman-ncc Hello and I am happy to share some thoughts. I studied this book for my qualifying exam and I compiled a list (e.g. "How to understand the spaces B and U on p. 64?") of statements that I cannot fathom after 20 minutes of concentrated construction on paper. I later asked a (now committee member) professor for their intuition, and they quite happily explained to me *everything*. The construction in this book is definitely worth it and can greatly sharpen your understanding. I consider asking for occasional assistance a must as these gaps reflected my lack of background knowledge.

Comment: @FrenzyLi : Thanks for your reply. Would you want to continue this conversation in chat? I had some other "logistic" questions regarding Brown's book and its exercises.

Comment: @sadman-ncc Don't know how much I could help but I am glad to move over to [Linear & Abstract Algebra](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13473/linear-abstract-algebra)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume $F$ is a field. Let's write $V$ instead of $\prod_{i\in \Delta}F$. Then $V$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over $F$.
Suppose the dimension of $V$ is $\frak a$. Then $V^*=\text{Hom}(V,F)$
is isomorphic to $F^{\frak a}$. The cardinality of $V$ is $\max(|F|,\frak a)$ and that of $V^*$ is $|F|^{\frak a}$. Certainly $|F|^{\frak a}
\ge 2^{\frak a}>\frak a$ (Cantor's theorem). But is it necessarily the case that $|F^{\frak a}|>|F|$?

I claim that $|{\frak a}|\ge |F|$. There is a well-known trick
to prove this: $V$ contains a subspace isomorphic to the
set of sequences $(a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ ($a\in F$). In this space
the elements $(1,a,a^2,\ldots)$ for $a\in F$ are linearly independent,
so ${\frak a}\ge|F|$. Therefore $|F^{\frak a}|\ge2^{\frak a}>|F|$?

In any case, there are also simple examples.
Take $F=\Bbb Q$ and $\Delta=\Bbb N$. Then $|V|=2^{\aleph_0}$
and $|V^*|=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

Comment: Wow, this is a lot more info than I had expected... First, if we let $\dim V=\frak a$, does this mean that $|\Delta|=\frak a$?

Comment: @FrenzyLi In general $\frak a$ will not be the same as $|\Delta|$. That's basically the point.

Comment: So, even when $V=\prod_{i\in \Delta}F$, $|V|=|\Delta|$ does not generally hold?

Comment: @FrenzyLi That is **never** true (Cantor).

Comment: So, the takeaway lesson is that, $|\hom_F(\prod_{i\in\Delta}F,F)|=|F|^{|F|^{\aleph_{0}}}$, $|\prod_{i\in\Delta}F|=|F|^{\aleph_{0}}$, and as long as $|F|>1$ (well, a field always contains at least 2 elements), the inequality holds?

Comment: It is not given that $|\Delta|=\aleph_0$. Anyway, I suspect the author is being lazy; the statement he gives is true, but is non-trivial, not something one can "easily see".

Comment: If $\Delta$ is finite, does $|\Hom_F(\prod_{i\in\Delta}F,F)|=|\prod_{i\in\Delta}F|$ hold?  If it doesn't, wouldn't the same argument work for finite $\Delta$?  I ask this because if we pick $F=\mathbb Q$ and $\Delta=\{1,2,3\}$, then $|V|={\aleph_0}^{3}={\aleph_0}$ and $|V^*|={\aleph_0}^{\aleph_0^3}=2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: When $\Delta$ is finite $\prod_{i \in \Delta}F$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$, its dimension is $|\Delta|$, and a finite dimensional vector space is always isomorphic to its dual space, in this case $Hom(\prod_{i \in \Delta} F,F)$, thus both sets have the same cardinality.